# Unable to start SAS [SASConfig-Lev1] services. ERROR: Unable to initialize the SAS kernel

Tags: sql-server, service, sas

When I am trying to start an automatic *SAS [SASConfig-Lev1]* service, I am getting:

> Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.

In the logs I found the following messages:

> ERROR: (SASXKINI): PHASE 3 KERNEL INITIALIZATION FAILED.
>   ERROR: Unable to initialize the SAS kernel.

How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Quote:

> The error indicates that the path defined for the SASUSER library is not currently accessible.
>
> The path for the SASUSER library is hardcoded into your SAS configuration file, which is named SASV8.cfg in SAS® 8 and SASV9.cfg in SAS 9.
>
> To resolve the problem, verify the path for SASUSER library in the SASv8.cfg or SASv9.cfg file and either make the path accessible or change the path.
> /quote

Follow the full instructions from :
http://support.sas.com/kb/12/457.html